# using gamma function to simplify integration

Tags: integration, improper-integrals, gamma-function

I have to evaluate $\int_0^1 x^2 \ln(\frac1x)^3 $.I used gamma function and used substitution $t=\ln (\frac {1}{x})^3$.
In this I get to integrate from $1$ to $-\infty$ with a minus sign outside.Because of this minus sign by  interchanging upper and lower limit 
I get to integrate from $+\infty$ to $1$.
Since $x>0$ I took this integration from 0 to 1.
Can I make that change of $+\infty$ => 0.

The answer I got is $\Gamma(2)=1$.Is this correct.Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let me  solve it from the first point. If I got correctly you are working on $$-\int_0^1x^2\ln^3(x)dx$$ Letting $x=\text{e}^{-y}$, the integral becomes $$(-1)^{4}\int_0^{\infty}y^3\text{e}^{-3y}dy$$ Now if we set $3y=u$, the latter integral becomes $$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{u^3}{3^3}\text{e}^{-u}\frac{du}{3}=\frac{1}{3^4}\Gamma(4)$$

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal Correct. There's just a factor of 3 missing somewhere.

Comment: Ahh... much better - just look closely at the definition of the gamma function!

Comment: @MarkMcClure: It is terrible for me. It really is. Thanks Mhenni. Thanks Mark. I just wanted to leave.

Comment: @BabakS.: No problem.

Comment: Thanks for the help.But I get minus value of the answer given

Comment: @clarkson: You have a minus from the start point. Have you considered that in your calculations?

Comment: yes.that minus sign and I get (-1)^3 from ln(e^-y)^3.and also when x=e^-y is differentiated with respect to y I get a minus sign.So altogether I get (-1)^5=-1

Comment: solved it.When using x=e^-y the lower limit becomes infinity and upper limit becomes 0.By taking the minus integral can integrate from 0 to infinity.Thanks for the help

Comment: @Babak Very well done!

Comment: @amWhy: Hi my dear friend.

Comment: Hello, good friend! Nice to "see" you, as always! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

According to WolframAlpha, the value of the integral is about $0.0740741$, which is certainly not $1$, so you've got an error somewhere.  Babak shows you how to use the gamma function but, since I've already typed it up, here's an outline of another approach.

Note that
$$\frac{d }{d x}\log ^n\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)=-\frac{n}{x} \log
   ^{n-1}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right).$$

This allows you to derive a reduction formula using integration by parts.  As a result, the indefinite integral is
$$
\frac{2 x^3}{27}+\frac{1}{3} x^3 \log
   ^3\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)+\frac{1}{3} x^3 \log
   ^2\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)+\frac{2}{9} x^3 \log
   \left(\frac{1}{x}\right).
$$

The limit of this as $x$ goes down to zero is zero and the limit as $x$ goes up to $1$ is $2/27$.  The the value of the integral is $2/27\approx 0.070741$.